# Manipulação de datas usando dplyr e lubridate

Tags: r, data, dplyr, lubridate, data-manipulation

Possuo um data frame cujas colunas possuem datas (%Y/%m/%d), horários e médias por hora ao longo de 4 meses (01/01/2020 - 01/04/2020). Desejo saber como eu poderia calcular a média desses valores horários, para cada dia, fazendo uso do pipe operator (%>%) ou de outra forma mais rápida. Vejam o meu código abaixo:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

head(dados)
       Data  Hora              Nome.Parâmetro Unidade.Medida Média.Horária
1 2020-01-03 01:00 MP10 (Partículas Inaláveis)          µg/m3            12
2 2020-01-03 02:00 MP10 (Partículas Inaláveis)          µg/m3            13
3 2020-01-03 03:00 MP10 (Partículas Inaláveis)          µg/m3             4
4 2020-01-03 04:00 MP10 (Partículas Inaláveis)          µg/m3             7
5 2020-01-03 05:00 MP10 (Partículas Inaláveis)          µg/m3            16
6 2020-01-03 06:00 MP10 (Partículas Inaláveis)          µg/m3            11
```

Executei o seguinte comando:

```
head(dados %>% 
  group_by(Data) %>% 
  summarise(med_dia = mean(dados$Média.Horária))
)

Data           med_dia
<date>          <dbl>
1 2020-01-03    22.8
2 2020-01-04    22.8
3 2020-01-05    22.8
4 2020-01-06    22.8
5 2020-01-07    22.8
6 2020-01-14    22.8
```

Após executar o código acima, eu esperava o cálculo de médias horárias por dia. Entretanto, o comando faz a soma de todas as colunas indiscriminadamente e repete o valor em todas as linhas.

Comment: Em vez de `mean(dados$Média.Horária)` tente remover o nome da base, `mean(Média.Horária)`.

Comment: Para termos os dados numa forma mais fácil de copiar para uma sessão do R, pode, por favor, **editar a pergunta** com a saída de `dput(dados)` ou, se a base for muito grande, de `dput(head(dados, 20))`?

Answer (score 0):

```
# Dados de exemplo
set.seed(4)
dados <- data.frame(Data = rep(paste0('2020-01-0', 1:3), each = 4),
                    Média.Horária = sample(1:20, 12, TRUE))
```

**Usando dplyr**

Como apontado por @rui-barradas, ao usar `group_by... mean(dados$Média.Horária)` você está indicando para tirar a média de todo o vetor e aplicar esse valor nos grupos. Simplesmente indique o nome da coluna:

```
library(dplyr)

> dados %>% group_by(Data) %>% summarise(med_dia = mean(Média.Horária))
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  Data       med_dia
  <fct>        <dbl>
1 2020-01-01   14.2 
2 2020-01-02    9.75
3 2020-01-03   15.5
```

**Usando data.table**

```
library(data.table)

setDT(dados)

> dados[, .(med_dia = mean(Média.Horária)), by = Data]
         Data med_dia
1: 2020-01-01   14.25
2: 2020-01-02    9.75
3: 2020-01-03   15.50
```